# Exactly is near-linear scalability supposed to be good scalability or bad scalability?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, nosql

I've been doing some reading on scalability and i came across the term **near-linear scalability**.

Exactly is **near-linear scalability** supposed to be good scalability or bad scalability?

Answer (score 1):

Near-linear is good, because the overhead by adding more resources (infrastructural overhead etc.) is so small, that a doubling of resources results in nearly a doubling of performance.

[Scalability Best Practices: Lessons from eBay](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ebay-scalability-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean with "scalability"?

I guess (near) linear sclability is good if you plan to scale horizontally.

However, I prefer the wider definition:

> [...] the ability of a system, network, or process, to handle growing amounts of work in a graceful manner. — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability

Speaking of databases, it can also mean how the system slows down if the data volume grows (algorithmic scalability). In that case, (near) linear scalability is not the best you can get, because proper indexing should give logarithmic scalability.

There is a chapter about that kind of scalability in SQL databases on my e-book: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/testing-scalability